# Can't load special files by php

Tags: php, html

I need to insert all the files (include audio, rar, folder, mp4, pdf) from my path to the table. But the file_exist() returns false when it meets audio, rar, mp4 even if these files existed and it just showed 2 pdf and folder. I tried to skip the file_exist() and two variables ($getSize, $getTime) throw 'stat failed' error. I also tried to use path_info in front of the file_exist() and the method returns all information of all files. How can I fix it? 
Thanks for support!

My folder tree: 
documents

- images (folder)
- files.rar (706KB)
- article.pdf (321KB)
- article2.pdf (556KB)
- music.mp3 (3840KB)
- video.mp4 (369KB)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="10" style="text-align: center; margin: auto; border-collapse: collapse">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
            <button>Back</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="header">
        <td>File name</td>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>Last modified</td>
        <td>File size</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."\Lab07\documents";
        // audio, rar, folder, mp4, text
        foreach(scandir($path) as $key => $value) {
            // print_r(pathinfo($value));
            if(file_exists($value)) {
                $getType = is_dir($value) ? "Folder" : "File";
                $getSize = round(filesize($value) / 1024,4) . 'KB';
                $getTime = date("d F Y", filemtime($value)) ?? "-";
                echo "
                    <tr>
                    <td><a href=\"#\">$value</a></td>
                    <td>$getType</td>
                    <td>$getTime</td>
                    <td>$getSize</td>
                    </tr>
                ";
            }
        }
    ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Paths are written with forward slashes, not back slashes.

Comment: and scandir wont return the full path, you need `if(file_exists($path.'/'.$value)) {`

Comment: @MarkusZeller  LawrenceCherone I've tried all your method already, nothing changed. Anyway thank you guys!

Comment: Could be a permissions problem, then. Make sure, the webserver is allowed to access them.